# Lightbox Jquery Plugin Not Working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

ive been working on my website but it seems that I cant get the lightbox plugin to work. I followed the steps written on the website and it still did not work. Any help would be appreciated.
you can find the page here, http://fuse.orgfree.com/Portfolio%202012/portfolio.html , when you click on the images it is supposed to start up the lightbox but I cant figure out why it wont work. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

The path for your lightbox library is incorrect

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lb/js/jquery.lightbox-0.4.js"></script>
```

I try to navigate that url but it returns `404 not found`.

The same applies for

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lb/css/jquery.lightbox-0.4.css" 
   media="screen" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have this in head

```
<script src="lb/js/jquery.lightbox-0.4.js" type="text/javascript">
```

I think it's supposed to be your lightbox script but it's not JS, it's HTML.  So your lightbox call is failing with

```
$("#gallery a").lightBox is not a function
```